# Method that returns a string of the concatenated elements of an array list

Tags: java, arraylist, methods

I have a method toString that is supposed to return a string of concatenated elements of an array list. The issue I am encountering is that an arraylist of type T (because its supposed to be generic) cannot be converted to string.

```
public class RandomStuffContainer<T extends Comparable<T>>
{
       ArrayList<T> array = new ArrayList<T>();

    public  void main(String[] args){
     ArrayList<T> array = new ArrayList<T>();

        
    }
public String toString() {
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       ArrayList<String> data = (ArrayList<T>)array.clone();
        for (String s : data)
        {
            sb.append(s);
            sb.append("\t");
    }
         return  data.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> The issue I am encountering is that an arraylist of type T (because its supposed to be generic) cannot be converted to string.

You don't need to convert it to a String. You just invoke the `toString()` method on the object when you want its String representation.

Also there is no need for the clone() since you are not changing any data in the ArrayList:

```
import java.util.*;

public class RandomStuffContainer<T extends Comparable<T>>
{
    ArrayList<T> array = new ArrayList<T>();

    public  void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<T> array = new ArrayList<T>();
    }

    public String toString() 
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        //ArrayList<String> data = (ArrayList<T>)array.clone(); // not needed

        //for (String s : array) // no need to use String here            
        for (T s : array)
        {
            //sb.append(s);
            sb.append(s.toString());
            sb.append("\t");
        }
        
        return  sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Also, instead of using the StringBuilder class you should use the `StringJoiner` class. This class will append the delimiter for you automatically and won't add the delimiter to the last token.

The above changes will just get the code to compile. It is still not a useable class since you have no methods to actually add data to the ArrayList and you have to code to create an instance of your RandomStuffContainer class.

Comment: Glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark (beside the answer) so people know the problem has been sovled.

Answer (score 0):

The code below is just a follow-up of @camickr answer giving an example of applying Java 8 Stream API to the required implementation of `toString` method:

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class RandomStuffContainer<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    List<T> array = new ArrayList<T>();

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return array.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining("\t"));
    }

    // provide constructor, add/remove methods, etc. as needed
}
```